# Get Palette (IntPtr) pointer from Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, bitmap

I need to convert a System.Drawing.Bitmap to System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.

The problem is that my bitmap has a custom palette and I need to pass it to CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap method.

How can obtain the pointer (IntPtr) of the bitmap palette?

Thanks.

```
IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

BitmapSource bmpSrc = CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap,
                                                    ????,
                                                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                                                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

Comment: What about `bitmap.Palette;` ?

Comment: that is, but I need to get the pointer to pass to CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap

Comment: You could declare method unsafe but it will likely fail with `unable to use managed object` here's example on how to get pointer `protected unsafe void Method(){ int i = 3; int* ptr1;ptr1 = &i;}`

Comment: It is actually a handle to a GDI palette, a HPALETTE.  You need to pinvoke CreatePalette() to obtain one.  This is unjoyful.

Comment: thanks, it is not necessary to specify the palette pointer. I had another problem.